# i am Generating a model from an existing database .Net Core 3.0 with VS Code using Terminal but it doesn't work

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, .net-core, visual-studio-code, scaffold

Added these packages

```xml
<ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore" Version="3.0.0"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational" Version="3.0.0"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" Version="3.0.0"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools" Version="3.0.0"/>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design" Version="3.0.0"/>
</ItemGroup>
```

and I am trying to run this command

```bsh
Scaffold-DbContext "Server=xxxx;Database=xxx;User Id=sa;Password=xx;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Context
```

just like .net core 2.0, but I get that:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

> Reverse engineering the database using `Scaffold-DbContext` can be
>   performed on the **NuGet Package Manager** console.

You're not using the Visual Studio NuGet Package Manager console, you're using a PS terminal. Therefore, you should use the command-line tool

```cs
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Server=xxxx;Database=xxx;User Id=sa;Password=xx;Trusted_Connection=True;" "Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer" --output-dir "Models/Scaffold" --context Context
```